# Find exact same string in multiple strings

Tags: php

The following example.

I have an array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  vlakke lasflenzen PN6
    [1] =>  vlakke lasflenzen PN10
    [2] =>  vlakke lasflenzen PN16
    [3] =>  vlakke lasflenzen PN25-40
)
```

I do not know what part of the strings will be the same. And i dont know if the pattern will stay the same. So i cannot explode() on spaces or something.

What i want to try is to extract the part of the srting that is exactly the same between all four of them but split between spaces.

So for this example I would need to extract 'vlakke lasflenzen' from the four strings based on compasison of them.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're talking about is also called [the longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

I found [an implementation for finding the longest common substring](https://gist.github.com/chrisbloom7/1021218) in an array of strings. As mentioned in the original post, usage:

```
<?php
$array = array(
  'PTT757LP4',
  'PTT757A',
  'PCT757B',
  'PCT757LP4EV'
);
echo longest_common_substring($array);
// => T757
?>
```

The relevant code:

```
function longest_common_substring($words)
{
  $words = array_map('strtolower', array_map('trim', $words));
  $sort_by_strlen = create_function('$a, $b', 'if (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) { return strcmp($a, $b); } return (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) ? -1 : 1;');
  usort($words, $sort_by_strlen);
  $longest_common_substring = array();
  $shortest_string = str_split(array_shift($words));
  while (sizeof($shortest_string)) {
    array_unshift($longest_common_substring, '');
    foreach ($shortest_string as $ci => $char) {
      foreach ($words as $wi => $word) {
        if (!strstr($word, $longest_common_substring[0] . $char)) {
          // No match
          break 2;
        } // if
      } // foreach
      $longest_common_substring[0].= $char;
    } // foreach
    array_shift($shortest_string);
  }
  // If we made it here then we've run through everything
  usort($longest_common_substring, $sort_by_strlen);
  return array_pop($longest_common_substring);
}
```

Comment: Works great! Just small addition, since OP wants to split by (last) space: $string=longest_common_substring($array); echo substr($string, 0 ,strrpos ( $string , ' ' ));

Comment: Thanks. I was using google as well, but did not know the name of the problem, because my native language is not english.

Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my own solutin to work.

```
$names = array[
    'vlakke lasflenzen PN6',
    'vlakke lasflenzen PN10',
    'vlakke lasflenzen PN16',
    'vlakke lasflenzen PN25-40'
];

$name = [];
$parts = [];
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $parts[] = array_filter(explode(' ', $name));
}

foreach ($parts[0] as $index => $part) {
        $match = true;
        foreach ($parts as $item) {
                if ($item[$index] !== $part)
                        $match = false;
        }
        if ($match)
                $name[] = ucfirst($part);
}


echo implode(' ', $name);
# Output : "Vlakke Lasflenzen"
```